# how to disable a zone damper and shut it OFF?

Tags: hvac, zoned-heating, motor

My system has a trol-a-temp mastertrol mark v model MABS-V-3 (three zone system) for HVAC.

I like to permanently disable zone 1 and physically shut off its damper for two reasons: Zone 1 is in an unfinished area (unused space) and its damper remains OPEN regardless of its thermostat calls. Which wire should I disconnect to remove the power to the trol-a-temp damper? and once the power is removed could the damper arm be moved to shutoff the damper?

Comment: Can you get a picture of the actual damper device in the ductwork?

Comment: Yeah, the actual damper model, rather than the control system is going to be the important part to answer your question. It may already be disconnected, since I note that one example of a "trol-a-temp" damper (of which there seem to be dozens of models) I looked at is power close, spring open, and considers this as "failing safe" by being open when unpowered.